# Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file using a base64 file source instead of url

Tags: javascript, pdf, canvas, base64, pdf.js

I'm trying to render a page from a pdf with pdf.js

Normally, using a url, I can do this:

```
PDFJS.getDocument("http://www.server.com/file.pdf").then(function getPdfHelloWorld(pdf) {
  //
  // Fetch the first page
  //
  pdf.getPage(1).then(function getPageHelloWorld(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

    //
    // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
    //
    var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    //
    // Render PDF page into canvas context
    //
    page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
  });
});
```

But in this case, I have the file in base64 rather than an url:

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUKJdDUxdgKNSAwIG9iaiA8PAovTGVuZ3RoIDE2NjUgICAgICAKL0ZpbHRlciAvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCnjarVhLc9s2...
```

How this can be done?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

from the sourcecode at
http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/build/pdf.js

```
/**
 * This is the main entry point for loading a PDF and interacting with it.
 * NOTE: If a URL is used to fetch the PDF data a standard XMLHttpRequest(XHR)
 * is used, which means it must follow the same origin rules that any XHR does
 * e.g. No cross domain requests without CORS.
 *
 * @param {string|TypedAray|object} source Can be an url to where a PDF is
 * located, a typed array (Uint8Array) already populated with data or
 * and parameter object with the following possible fields:
 *  - url   - The URL of the PDF.
 *  - data  - A typed array with PDF data.
 *  - httpHeaders - Basic authentication headers.
 *  - password - For decrypting password-protected PDFs.
 *
 * @return {Promise} A promise that is resolved with {PDFDocumentProxy} object.
 */
```

So a standard XMLHttpRequest(XHR) is used for retrieving the document. 
The Problem with this is that XMLHttpRequests do not support data: uris (eg. data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUK...).

But there is the possibility of passing a typed Javascript Array to the function.
The only thing you need to do is to convert the base64 string to a Uint8Array. You can use this function found at https://gist.github.com/1032746

```
var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';

function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
  var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
  var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
  var raw = window.atob(base64);
  var rawLength = raw.length;
  var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

  for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
    array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array;
}
```

**tl;dr**

```
var pdfAsDataUri = "data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUK..."; // shortened
var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(pdfAsDataUri);
PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray)
```

Comment: so will it be possible to fetch the binary of pdf and show it in the pdf viewer using pdf.js

Comment: Nice work. But what if the source is PDF retrieved via a RESTful call into an arraybuffer or blob? I posted a question on it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24288221/pdf-js-render-pdf-using-an-arraybuffer-or-blob-instead-of-url

Comment: Don't forget the `var` before `i = 0` if you are in `strict mode`! I lost 1 hour for nothing. :)

Comment: I got this to work. My answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535799/pdf-js-and-viewer-js-pass-a-stream-or-blob-to-the-viewer/32634740#32634740)

Comment: I like arrays :-) `var base64 = dataURI.split(BASE64_MARKER)[1];`

Answer (score 5):

[According to the examples](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) base64 encoding is directly supported, although I've not tested it myself. Take your base64 string (derived from a file or loaded with any other method, POST/GET, websockets etc), turn it to a binary with atob, and then parse this to getDocument on the PDFJS API like`PDFJS.getDocument({data: base64PdfData});` Codetoffel answer does work just fine for me though.

Comment: I have tested it using the nodejs package with `PDFJS.getDocument({data: Buffer.from(pdf_base64, 'base64')})`

Answer (score 0):

Used the Accepted Answer to do a check for IE and convert the dataURI to UInt8Array; an accepted form by PDFJS

```js
        Ext.isIE ? pdfAsDataUri = me.convertDataURIToBinary(pdfAsDataUri): '';

        convertDataURIToBinary: function(dataURI) {
          var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,',
            base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length,
            base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index),
            raw = window.atob(base64),
            rawLength = raw.length,
            array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

          for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
            array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          return array;
        },
```