# Convert PDF to a Base64-encoded string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, canvas, base64

I need to encode a PDF file to Base64 with Javascript. I can create Base64-encoded jpeg or png images in Javascript, but I could not find any way or sample code to create a Base64-encoded string from a PDF file.

Is it there any solution using a HTML5 canvas?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url

and 

.window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + Base64.encode(out));

Comment: STOP! don't use base64 anymore. there are better ways to handle binary data. like using ObjectURLs, blobs and typed arrays. `open(URL.createObjectURL(file))`

Answer (score 44):

Try this :-

```
<input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertToBase64() {
        //Read File
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("inputFile").files;
        //Check File is not Empty
        if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
            // Select the very first file from list
            var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
            // FileReader function for read the file.
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var base64;
            // Onload of file read the file content
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                // Print data in console
                console.log(base64);
            };
            // Convert data to base64
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This solution works great across browsers and filetypes

Answer (score 2):

Here is how one person did it:

- http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2009/08/base64_encode_a_pdf_attachment.html

Here is a link that suggests several other possible solutions:

- [Base64 encoding and decoding in client-side Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820249/base64-encoding-and-decoding-in-client-side-javascript)

Comment: i saw this link before and gave it a try after you adviced this link too http://blogs.adobe.com/formfeed/2009/08/base64_encode_a_pdf_attachment.html this one works for txt files but not for pdf.  when i write var inputStream = event.target.getDataObjectContents("1.pdf"); 
      document.getElementById('data2').value = inputStream; it does not return any value. Also the second link that you shared does not contain anything about pdf to string conversion. It shows about base64 encoding only and i have no problem with base64 encoding an image or a string.

Comment: My point is to get the base64 encoded string representation of a pdf file.

Comment: @onuryilmaz have you found the answer ? I have the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

```js
     function Selectfile() {
        document.getElementById('fileInput').click();
    };

     function handleFileSelect (event) {
        var selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
        if (selectedFile) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (event) {
            
                    var selectedFile = selectedFile;
                    // Convert the file to Base64
                    var selectedFileBase64 = event.target.result.split(',')[1];
                    console.log(selectedFileBase64);
               
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
        }
    };
    document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);
```

```html
<button onclick="Selectfile()">Browse</button>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none;"/>
```