# Convert PDF file into Base64 string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64

I have a link to a local pdf file and I need that file as a base64 string. I'm programming with JavaScript. 
Does anybody know how I can get this string?

**UPDATE:**

I have to file object because I downloaded the pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert PDF to a Base64-encoded string in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538832/convert-pdf-to-a-base64-encoded-string-in-javascript)

Comment: You shouldn't have to base64 the pdf... why do you need that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
<input id="inputFile" type="file" onchange="convertToBase64();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function convertToBase64() {
        //Read File
        var selectedFile = document.getElementById("inputFile").files;
        //Check File is not Empty
        if (selectedFile.length > 0) {
            // Select the very first file from list
            var fileToLoad = selectedFile[0];
            // FileReader function for read the file.
            var fileReader = new FileReader();
            var base64;
            // Onload of file read the file content
            fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
                base64 = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
                // Print data in console
                console.log(base64);
            };
            // Convert data to base64
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
</script>
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37699333/5928577)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure where I should put my link. What does `document.getElementById("inputFile").files;`? Does it return an array of "Files"?

Comment: I think it isn't possible to get a file object from an url. Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

With [Screw-FileReader](https://github.com/jimmywarting/Screw-FileReader) & [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch)

```
fetch('/file.pdf')
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => blob.dataUrl())
.then(base64 => console.log(base64))
```

I could give you a few reason why you don't need the base64 string and why it's inconvenient. But i don't know why you need it... The overall reason is [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) and that it's ~3x larger