# Send multiple response back for a POST API request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way to send back a file (.pdf) and JSON data in the body for a POST WebAPI request in .NET ?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the PDF file to a base64 string, and put it in the JSON. To convert a PDF into a base64 string in JS, start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538832/convert-pdf-to-a-base64-encoded-string-in-javascript). To convert back to the file in .Net, use [Convert.FromBase64String](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Possible but not recommended. The normal way is to return a json which also contains an url to the fat data. It should be up to the consumer when to get that huge amount of data

Answer (score 0):

If the JSON is not very big, then you could return the PDF document normally and the JSON in a HTTP header like some metadata. Maybe this is not best practice, but could work.