# FileReader losing data when reading PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, filereader

I have the constraint of sending data to a server in JSON format only, and I need to send a PDF file together with other form data in the JSON. I though I could make a string from it with base64 like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37699333/2197181) I found on SO:

```
let data = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(pdf);
reader.onload = () => {
  data.file = reader.result;
  $.ajax({type: 'POST', dataType: "json", data: JSON.stringify(data), ...});
}
```

But it happened that `reader.result` does not contain the whole PDF (whether I save it to file instead of sending, or get it back from the server). In a text editor the content is the same, but a binary editor says that some bytes are missing. My browser can load it as a pdf and the title shows, but the page is blank.

I also tried `reader.readAsBinaryString` and transform to base64 myself with `btoa`, but same result.

**Edit**: CodePen example: https://codepen.io/jdelafon/pen/eRWLdz?editors=1011

**Edit**: to verify, I did this:

```
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsBinaryString(pdf);
reader.onload = () => {
    let blob = reader.result;
    let file = new Blob([blob], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
    // make it display in <embed>
};
```

The body of the pdf is empty. If I replace `file` by the original `pdf`, it gets displayed entirely. So FileReader loses data in the process.

[image: It knows the title and number of pages, but the body of each page is empty]

Is there a better way? Is it an encoding issue with `FileReader`?

I also though about using FormData like this:

```
let data = {foo: 1, bar: 2};
let fd = new FormData();
fd.append('file', pdf);
data.file = btoa(fd);
$.ajax({type: 'POST', dataType: "json", data: JSON.stringify(data), ...});
```

But now when I fetch the data back from the server, JS has no idea that it represents a FormData object, so I don't know how to get the file back for display in a browser. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure the data is truncated in the browser, not on the server?

Comment: @Bergi yes, because I can display it directly in the browser before sending it, and I can compare with the original file, before passing through FileReader. I added the code for that in my question. The original file comes from a <input type="file">.

Comment: try removing `dataType: "json"` I'm not really sure if it would work. it's just a theory.

Comment: @perseusl the data is truncated before I send it with Ajax. Maybe I should write a new question without the json context. Plus if it is a string, it should not be different from other strings from the json point of view.

Comment: Does this only happen for PDFs? Files of a certain size?

Comment: @Bergi I do not know for other kinds of files, I will try to test with an image. My pdfs are quite small, below 100KB.

Comment: Could you somehow share an example file which reproduces this problem ? Do all browsers have the same behavior ? Encoding should not be a problem for readAsDataURL, it would be only for readAsText. Oh and maybe silly question, but do you have an ad-blocker enabled ?

Comment: @Kaiido I created a CodePen that reproduces the problem: https://codepen.io/jdelafon/pen/eRWLdz?editors=1011. Ad-block yes, but it works for the original file. Firefox and Chrome have the same problem.

Comment: But it's not what your question is about... Yes you're doing it wrong, you can't simply pass the result of **deprecated** `readAsBinaryString` into `new Blob([str])`, there will probably be an encoding issue from this binary data. If you really want to do it this way, you need to first convert this binary string to an arrayBuffer, and then create an Blob from the arrayBuffer. Your question states that `readAsDataURL` doesn't work, but I can't repro : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRWBxP?editors=1011

Comment: @Kaiido That works, thanks!! You have no idea how long I've been trying. Would you like to copy your CodePen snippet as an answer and I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watilin's answer was not added, so here is the working snippet copied from Codepen:

```
function onUpload(input) {  
  let originalFile = input.files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(originalFile);
  reader.onload = () => {
    let json = JSON.stringify({ dataURL: reader.result });

    // View the file
    let fileURL = JSON.parse(json).dataURL;
    $("#display-pdf").empty();
    $("#display-pdf").append(`<object data="${fileURL}"
      type="application/pdf" width="400px" height="200px">
    </object>`);

    // View the original file
    let originalFileURL = URL.createObjectURL(originalFile);
    $("#display-pdf").append(`<object data="${originalFileURL}"
      type="application/pdf" width="400px" height="200px">
    </object>`)
    .onload(() => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(originalFileURL);
    });
  };
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" onchange="onUpload(this)" />
<div id="display-pdf"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You weren’t far from succeeding when you tried `btoa`, except you can’t “btoa-ize” a FormData.

```js
reader.readAsBinaryString(pdf); // don’t use this! See edit below
reader.onload = () => {
  let b64payload = btoa(reader.result);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "file": b64payload }),
  });
}
```

I’m not sure why the `readAsDataURL` solution failed though.

---

**Edit:** although not sure, it’s been suspected that the deprecated `readAsBinaryString` method might be the source of the problem. The following solution, based on `readAsDataURL`, is working:

```js
reader.readAsDataURL(pdf);
reader.onload = () => {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "dataURL": reader.result }),
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried this too, and yet the PDF gets truncated. I feel like this method sends the "content" of the pdf, not the file itself. To verify, I did in sequence, from your  `b64payload`, -> `atob` -> `new Blob` -> `URL.createObjectURL` -> display in `<embed>`. The boby of the pdf is empty. The original pdf gets displayed entirely.

Comment: Here’s a working example with `readAsDataURL`: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzwyeP?editors=1011
Next thing to do is checking if it survives an ajax trip.

Comment: Many thanks, that is the example I needed - looks like Kaiido's. I don't see why a b64 string wouldn't survive the trip. I just checked and it did. Awesome.

Comment: So can we conclude the question by saying `readAsBinaryString` was the culprit? Also, we didn’t explore the `readAsArrayBuffer` option.

Comment: Yes, and my misunderstanding of how `readAsDataURL` is actually used. If you post your snippet as answer I can vote it up.

Comment: @MrD It might be that your pdf file is too large. In this case you can’t use a data URL, you have to send the file separately from the json.