# Encoding a remote URL PDF to BASE64 (javascript)

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64

I am trying to encode a PDF that is remotely on a server (not locally neither selecting files using a javascript/HTML "Browse" button) into BASE64.

I already have checked some examples kindly given by others in StackOverflow such as:

[Convert PDF to a Base64-encoded string in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538832/convert-pdf-to-a-base64-encoded-string-in-javascript)

[How to convert file to base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280818/how-to-convert-file-to-base64-in-javascript)

But every time I pass the variable where the remote URL for the PDF is, it shows an error saying:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.

```
function funcTransfPDFParaBase64(strCaminhoPDF) {
var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.readAsDataURL(strCaminhoPDF)
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
   
   return reader.result;
}

var objTeste = funcTransfPDFParaBase64(strCaminhoPDF);
```

URL type used in var strCaminhoPDF: `https://somesite/fs/file/Download/FileShare/www/Legislation/2015/DL_2015021028.pdf`

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem - why do you need to *encode* (what can be assumed to be an unencoded) PDF from the server?

Comment: [MDN FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) states *To read server-side files, use standard Ajax solutions*.   FileReader is for reading local files (eg via an `input`).

Comment: It is to encode freedomm. Why do I need? Boss told it. lol

Comment: [readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) can't be used to read from a remote URL, but is made for data in form of a so called [Data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), e.g `data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJe...`, in which the data is already embedded as base64 string.

Comment: Hello jps, yes I know that now, but what I can do? Asynchronous read?