# Right way to output a pdf stream returned to ajax call success method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, pdf

I have a webpage in wordpress.

In a page template I make a call via Ajax to a php function that returns a pdf stream made by php-pdftk library call.
The pdf stream seems to return fine to the success event of the jquery ajax call, but I can not find a way to send this stream to the browser.
It seems there is no direct way to output to a new browser  window nor a object or a embed in the same document.

I have read almost every answer to this question in SO and other sites, but it seems it cannot be done.

Does anyone find a way to do this from JS or Jquery, or this is impossible from the conceptual point of view?
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Have the php function create a tempory file in a web accesable location, and return the url. The js success function then simply directs the browser to open the url

Comment: Thanks Steve,  I assume your answer means that there is no way (or easy way) to output the pdf stream directly to browser then?

Comment: Not in my experience - i did pretty much the same research you have just done last year, and ended up using the above method. There are things like http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ that could be used, but i decided the effort to implement it was unjustifiable. There are SO questions that might help if you still want to try that route: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535799/pdf-js-and-viewer-js-pass-a-stream-or-blob-to-the-viewer

Comment: Just one more tought, when you would erase that pdf from server? A cron on the server that makes a "garbage collect" all the pdf files? Or how?

Comment: Yes, a cron job is what i used. Alternatively you can ditch the ajax all together, and instead create a hidden form that submits the data that you want, so the returned pdf data stream is handled directly by the browser (resulting in a download, or open if browser has pdf ability)

Comment: If you don't want to generate a file then have a cron job clean it up, I would highly recommend DomPDF. It can stream it directly to the browser.