# Display PDF Content in an Aurelia View

Tags: pdf, aurelia, pdf.js

I have some PDF files that I need to display in an Aurelia View.
The files are not available by direct link
I have an API function that returns a byte array.

In ASP.Net, I have some control over the response object's headers and content type, and can BinaryWrite the contents into the response.

I can't figure out how to do this in Aurelia.
Any suggestions?

Edit: 
I'm attempting to use pdf.js as suggested. Injection in Aurelia fails.

```
import {inject} from "aurelia-framework";
import {HttpClient} from "aurelia-fetch-client";
import {PDF} from "pdfjs-dist"

@inject(Router, HttpClient, PDF)
export class PDFView {

    constructor(router, http, pdf) {

        this.router = router;
        this.http = http;
        this.pdf = pdf;

    }
```

The console displays this error:

```
Inner Error:
Message: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
Inner Error Stack:
Error: key/value cannot be null or undefined. Are you trying to inject/register something that doesn't exist with DI?
    at Container.get (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:480:15)
    at Object.invoke (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:341:81)
    at InvocationHandler.invoke (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:300:168)
    at Container.invoke (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:564:25)
    at StrategyResolver.get (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:127:37)
    at Container.get (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-dependency-injection@1.0.0-beta.1.2.3/aurelia-dependency-injection.js:501:23)
    at eval (http://localhost:65397/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-templating@1.0.0-beta.1.2.7/aurelia-templating.js:3925:73)
End Inner Error Stack
------------------------------------------------
```

The import statement must be failing, yet pdfjs appears to load successfully as I receive status 200 for both pdfjs-dist@1.5.294.js and pdfjs when the page loads.

I can find no samples of Aurelia / pdfjs apps. 
Repeating: I need to embed the stream as the PDF is not available via HTTP.

I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: I'm also struggling to find any examples. Did you ever manage to find a proper example?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is nothing Aurelia-specific about loading pdf files.

You can use [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js). It has method **getDocument** that accepts binary data stored in byte array.

Then you can place a canvas inside your view, load pdf data during view activation and render pages into it using pdf.js after html is attached. For example code check answer by [toddmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045881/toddmo) for this post: [Pdf.js and viewer.js. Pass a stream or blob to the viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535799/pdf-js-and-viewer-js-pass-a-stream-or-blob-to-the-viewer)