# Pull PDF from Amazon S3 and render directly in Browser from buffer/stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3

I have a requirement where PDFs aren't kept on a local server but stored privately on the Amazon S3 bucket. But upon specific requests, I need to retrieve the PDF and render it directly in the user's browser without downloading it on the web server.

I am able to pull the stream fine in node.js and respond with the PDF data. When I inspect the response data in the Chrome dev tools, it looks like the PDF data, and I can even read the text in the document.

```
let params = {Bucket: process.env.S3STORAGE, Key: req.query.fileName};
res.attachment(req.query.fileName);
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(res);
```

And I've tried multiple things to render it correctly. It is either displaying a blank PDF, or the gobbly gook PDF data.

I am using a vue2 template, and trying to pop the PDF in a bootstrap modal. In this attempt, I get a blank PDF:

```
<object :data="pdfStream" type="application/pdf" width="800px" :height="browserHeight"></object>


this.pdfStream = response.bodyText;
```

I saw some answers that said base64 encode it, but still not getting that to work either.

```
// server side
let params = {Bucket: process.env.S3STORAGE, Key: req.query.fileName};
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(strs('binary', 'base64')).pipe(res);
```

Then

```
//client side
 let objbuilder = '';
        objbuilder += ('<object width="100%" height="100%" data="data:application/pdf;base64,');
        objbuilder += (response.bodyText);
        objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf" class="internal">');
        objbuilder += ('<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,');
        objbuilder += (response.bodyText);
        objbuilder += ('" type="application/pdf"  />');
        objbuilder += ('</object>');
        this.pdfStream = objbuilder;
```

Surely I am missing something simple, or making a dumb mistake, but not sure what it is. I have always just served up actual files, but in this specific instance, the goal is to just render the data directly into the browser without generating a copy of the PDF sitting in S3 storage.

**UPDATE**

Jason's answer is pointing me in the right direction, and I believe I am now on the right track. However it's throwing errors I am unsure of.

My first attempt is this:

```
// returning a base64 encoded PDF from Amazon to the client
let params = {Bucket: process.env.S3STORAGE, Key: req.query.fileName};
s3.getObject(params).createReadStream().pipe(strs('binary', 'base64')).pipe(res);
```

Then in the client side Vue component:

```
//import PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';
export default {
  {components: PDFJS},
  ...
  ...

  ...
  viewDocument(fileName, documentName) {

      this.$http.get('/fetchDocument', {
        params: {
          fileName: fileName
        }
      })
      .then(response => {

         PDFJS.getDocument(response.bodyText).then(function (pdfDocument) {

          console.log('Number of pages: ' + pdfDocument.numPages);

        });
      });

    },
```

And it shoots back this error:

```
app.js:58668 GET http://192.168.3.14:3000/dist/app.worker.js net::ERR_ABORTED
app.js:55073 Warning: Setting up fake worker.
app.js:104 GET http://192.168.3.14:3000/0.js net::ERR_ABORTED
app.js:99 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (app.js:99)
```

There is no `app.worker.js` or `0.js` in the pdfjs-dist library.

Then...if I return from node the original way without base64 and it returns the raw PDF stream that starts like:

```
%PDF-1.2
%����
3 0 obj
<< 
/Lineariz
```

I get an entirely different error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

Finally, I tried the `base64Uint8Array` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24535799/pdf-js-and-viewer-js-pass-a-stream-or-blob-to-the-viewer) on the base64 encoded data returned from node, which led to the app.worker.js and 0.js 404 errors I just received.

The pdfjs-dist package does not have those js files, so not sure what is exactly happening.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the header, like here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10047018/5734311

Comment: I hadn't yet, but I will when I get home tonight. However the response headers currently show:

Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="1513046394445.pdf"
Content-Type:application/pdf

Comment: the key here is you need to pull the viewer component from the web folder: `import {PDFJS as PDFJSViewer} from 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';` and then go from there

Comment: @Jason Thank you. I'll keep trying and open a new question if I can't get it to work.

Comment: did you get this working @Nathan. If so, can you post it here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a renderer to render the PDF data into the browser.  One such project is Mozilla's [PDF.JS project](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).  Since you're using vue, you can look at this example for usage: https://github.com/shershen08/vue2-pdfjs-viewer

Browsers already have PDF readers built into them, but not in the context of a JS application.  That's where the PDF.JS project comes into the picture.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added an update to my question if you have any insight.