# how to convert html to pdf in modal with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a task to do where i have to show pdf in bootstrap modal with out the download option.That pdf would have input fields where user can upload its signature and when user would click okay it would save respective pdf with filled information. I tried to do so,with Bootstrap modal i am able to show the form with input options in modal pop up, but i want whatever i write in modal,it should show up as pdf and that to with out doanload option.

I am searching answer in Jquery,i saw jsPDF but all tutorials show how to download html2pdf.I just want to show user to read it first not download.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div style="text-align: center;" class="test">
            <div>
                <hr><h2>Contract</h2><hr>
                <h3>Hereby,i buy LaLaLa Land in the exchange of 2 cookies.</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="signature">
                <hr><h2>Signature Page</h2><hr>

                    <img class="profile-pic" />
                    <div class="upload-button"></div>
                    <input class="file-upload" type="file" accept="image/*"/>

                <h4>Document ID:dlfkhahdf4565n5jbnjk45h</h4>
                <h4>User Name:Donald Trump</h4>
                <h4>User ID:456jkn45</h4>
            </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Okay</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why vote down! you can explain instead of just voting down!

Comment: I don't see what the problem is with this question. It's specific and answerable; apart from a few typos, it's alright.

Answer (score 0):

Simply display the `data:` URI of the created PDF in an `iframe`, or use PDF.js to show it:

```js
// Set up jsPDF
var pdf = new jsPDF();

// Set up PDF.js
//pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
//  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.0.943/pdf.worker.min.js';

function render_example() {
  var source = document.getElementById("convert_me_to_pdf");
  pdf.fromHTML(source, function (dispose) {
    var pdf_uri = pdf.output("datauristring");
    document.getElementById("show_pdf_here").src = pdf_uri;

    var pdf_array = pdf.output("arraybuffer");
    // PDF.js here!
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-THVO/sM0mFD9h7dfSndI6TS0PgAGavwKvB5hAxRRvc0o9cPLohB0wb/PTA7LdUHs" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button onclick="render_example()">Render</button>

<h1>Output</h1>
<h2><code>&lt;iframe&gt;</code></h2>
<iframe id="show_pdf_here" src="//www.example.org"></iframe>
<h2>PDF.js</h2>
Requires CORS to be disabled; cannot write. See <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/32634740/5223757">here</a> for an implementation.
<iframe src="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html"></iframe>

<h1>Input</h1>
<div id="convert_me_to_pdf">
  <p>
    Example...
  </p>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Erm... This *should* work... I don't know why it doesn't. I'm posting it anyway in case it helps.

Comment: so, that render should download the pdf or just show the pdf in the browser.

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak It should show it in the browser. Basically, instead of using `pdf.save`, use `pdf.output("datauristring")` and then set the `src` of an `iframe` to that.

Comment: so here `document.getElementById("show_pdf_here").src = pdf_uri;` instead of show_pdf_here i should give my modal class or id?

Comment: @ChidanandaNayak If the modal is an `<iframe>` that you want to display the PDF in, yes. But this example doesn't actually work; use your mostly-working-but-downloads-instead-of-shows version instead.