# passin raw data to pdfJS instead of url?

Tags: javascript, pdf

can i pass data like this to PDFJS.getDocument instead of URL. my data:

> PDF-1.4
>   %���� 9 0 obj <> endobj
>                      xref 9 36 0000000016 00000 n 0000001259 00000 n 0000001336 00000 n...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The PDFJS.getDocument method is defined pretty clearly, and you can read it for yourself: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/PDFJS.html#getDocument

You can open a PDF using a URL:

```
PDFJS.getDocument('/url/to/file.pdf').then(function(pdf){ 

    var pageNumber = 1;

    pdf.getPage(pageNumber).then(function (page) {
        var scale = 1;
        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
        var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = viewport.height;
        canvas.width = viewport.width;
        page.render({canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport});
    });
});
```

In this case, PDFJS makes a call to the URL for you, but if you already have the PDF file, you can just give the data to PDFJS, like this:

```
var docInitParams = { data: myPdfContent };
PDFJS.getDocument(docInitParams).then(function(pdf){
    //render a page here
});
```

**The question is what format is your raw PDF data in?**

If you just retrieved the file from your webserver using an Ajax call, then perhaps the data is in an `ArrayBuffer`. If so, you'll need to make it accessible to PDFJS by putting it in a `Uint8Array`, as follows:

```
//However you get the data, let's say it ends up here in this variable
var arrayBufferOfPdfData = blah..blah..blah;

var myData = new Uint8Array(arrayBufferOfPdfData); //put it in a Uint8Array

var docInitParams = {data: myData};
PDFJS.getDocument(docInitParams).then(function(pdf){
    //render a page here
});
```

In the end, you need to know what format your data is in so that you can get it into an acceptable format for PDFJS to make use of. I didn't describe what to do if your data is encoded as a Base64 string, but there is [another SO question that answers exactly that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url).

My answer is much more descriptive than your one-liner question. So, if I haven't addressed your question well enough, then you should provide more detail.