# How to store PDF.js document in local storage? How To use viewer.js with raw pdf source?

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have 2 questions revolving around displaying pdfs in a browser.

When I try to store a PDF.js document in local storage it does not work and crashes the javascript. Code below.

```
PDFJS.getDocument(array).then(function getPdfHelloWorld(_pdfDoc) {
    localStorage.setItem("pageNum", pageNum);
    localStorage.setItem("pdf-obj", JSON.stringify(_pdfDoc));
    pdfDoc = _pdfDoc;
    renderPage(pageNum);
  });
```

Any ideas?

Also since I may not be able to use paging this way I may need to look into using viewer.js for display and paging. I am wondering if there is a way to use viewer.js with raw pdf source rather than a file because that is all I have available to me. Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is PDFJS, Where are you getting the PDF Content from?

Comment: It is a javascript library that allows you to display pdfs right in the browser. The array I'm handing it is raw pdf source and the _pdfDoc is the document ready to be displayed in the page.

Comment: So you are basically trying to store binary data on the localstorage?

Comment: Not sure. It's a javascript object I'm trying to store not the unencoded base64 string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**How to store PDF.js document in local storage?**

[PDFJS.getDocument](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/PDFJS.html) returns a [PDFDocumentProxy](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/PDFDocumentProxy.html) object which is quite likely not JSON serializable. (Check developer console output to this effect, it would help if your question stated HOW the javascript code is crashing). It is lik

**How To use viewer.js with raw pdf source?**

An ArrayBuffer can be passed to getDocument. See [Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file using a base64 file source instead of url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12094943/331858).

Comment: The code is crashing by not reading any more lines of code after I try to store the PDFDocumentProxy so you're probably right. As far as the viewer.js. I already am using an array buffer with pdf.js. What I want is to use viewer.js(google it) so I will be able to page through the document and download the file instead of just seeing the first page. Thanks.