# Open pdf.js with a data URL in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, pdf.js

I'm trying to use pdf.js for showing a document in a data URL on IE10. That is, [something like this](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwogIC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo%20PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAvTWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0KPj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAgL1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA%20PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo%20PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9udAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2JqCgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJUCjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVuZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9vdCAxIDAgUgo%20PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G).

It works well with Firefox or Chrome, but in Internet Explorer 10 and 11, the interface is shown, but stays empty, and the document never loads.

I checked, compatibility.js is included in the renderer page (viewer.html), so IE support should be present.

EDIT: actually it's a security issue, as IE doesn't let to run a request of this type.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Convert your data URL to byte array and use to open using PDFViewerApplication.open?

Comment: Keep in mind than IE also truncates the long URL, so your base64 encoded PDF can be corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if someone runs to the same problem, I solved it by bypassing the lib's  normal loading path, and as async5 advised, converting directly the data to a byte array.

That is, in viewer.js, add those lines under line 6856 :

```
  if (file && file.lastIndexOf('data:', 0) === 0) {
      // data: url-scheme. we will load those with direct conversion to byte array

      function convertDataURIToBinary(dataURI) {
          var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
          var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);
          var raw = window.atob(base64);
          var rawLength = raw.length;
          var array = new Uint8Array(new ArrayBuffer(rawLength));

          for(var i = 0; i < rawLength; i++) {
              array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
          }
          return array;
      }

      // PDFViewerApplication.setTitleUsingUrl(file);
      PDFViewerApplication.open(convertDataURIToBinary(file), 0);

      return;
  }
```

(the base64 to byte array code is the one posted by Codetoffel [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12094943/150015))

Comment: Which is the PDFViewerApplication in this case?...adobe reader?

Comment: No it's a class that is internal to pdf.js

Comment: Isnt there any other workaround that using pdf.js for just making it work in IE11?...i mean thats too much of overhead for just support in IE :(

Comment: You can indeed open PDFs in an external application, Adobe, or Window's Reader app.