# Running an XMLHttpRequest on a "data:" URL on Internet Explorer 10

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to run an XHR request on an URL of type "data:application/pdf;base64,..."

It works well on other browsers, but on IE11 I get an "Access refused" error.

Is there any way to make a request of this type work in IE ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why? Just strip off the preamble and decode the base64 data instead.

Comment: Well I need to pass the data to pdf.js so it can display it. But the lib uses XHR at its core for all requests, which works well in Firefox or Chrome, but not IE. I'm trying to make it work, without re-writing the whole loading layer of pdf.js.

Comment: Did you ever find a work around for this?

Comment: I did, though it was a very specific workaround. My goal was to display the data as a PDF, so what I did was to modify pdf.js' source code to bypass the call to XMLHttpRequest, as I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915805/150015). I guess as long as IE doesn't accept "data:..." requests, the best aim is to seek similar solutions, bypassing the call to XMLHttpRequest altogether.