# PDF.js rendering a base64 pdf in .Net

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, pdf.js

I have a Xamarin WindowsRT project where I am able to load a local PDF and view it within the WebView of the app using PDF.js.

I have created a custom renderer to override the Xamarin WebView and I simply call:

```
Control.Source = new Uri("ms-appx-web:///Assets/pdf/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=mypdf.pdf");
```

And this works great for opening and viewing the PDF.

The thing is, the PDFs I will need to view are in the form of base64 encoded strings downloaded from a server.  Is there a way to pass the base64 to PDF.js somehow?

Update:

Just to see if I can get this working using javascript, I am loading a basic html page into the webview with the following script, but I just get a blank page:

```
<script>
    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary('data:application/pdf;base64,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');
    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray);
</script>
```

I know the html page is loading because above the script i put TEST and that renders.  And it is executing the javascript.  It is also properly creating the pdfAsArray, because I also iterated through it and it has a lot of values.

Answer (score 1):

Fetch your pdf string using C# and then inject it as a variable in your `WebView` in order to pass it (since you're using Xamarin.Forms, you can use [HybridWebView](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/HybridWebView)'s [InjectJavaScript](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/HybridWebView.cs#L216))

Then, use the function from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746) to convert that string into an array that can be accepted by pdf.js, as pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12094943/3465182).

```
var pdfAsDataUri = //Your string;
var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(pdfAsDataUri);
PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray)
```

---

You can also create a function that wraps the conversion and the `PDFJS.getDocument` and call it directly from C#:

```
//JS
function loadPdfFromBase64(pdfString) {
    var pdfAsArray = convertDataURIToBinary(pdfString);
    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfAsArray)
}

//C#
hybridWebView.CallJsFunction("loadPdfFromBase64", yourPdfString);
```

Comment: Side note, I tried loading like this, which works in firefox and chrome, but did not load in the webview:  viewer.htmlfile=data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjcK...

Comment: I can't figure out how to do the IOC in WindowsApp.

Comment: Which IoC? The one used by the HybridWebView for Json Serializer?

Comment: Yes, see here:  http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/48284/hybridwebview-in-windows-app#latest

Comment: Any progress on this, @Jesse?