# PDF.JS with base64 data uri doesn't work on safari

Tags: javascript, pdf, safari, base64, pdf.js

I am using PDF JS demo app and I give a base64 pdf from the server to the viewer. This does work very good on chrome and mozilla(both desktop and mobile) but it doesn't work at all on Safari.

I think the issue is because of the XHR but I don't have that much experience so I can't say for sure.

What are my alternatives ?

Comment: I have used PDF JS and that worked perfectly in all browser. I created the base64 url to pdf on my server and sent that link to the PDF JS.

Comment: I get something like "Warning, setting up fake worker. and Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP."

Comment: But still that should be working

Comment: In my console it says XMLHttpRequest cannot load base64 string. I verified the base64 string and it is correct.

Comment: See helloworld w/base64 example https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/helloworld64.html

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by converting the base64 to binary with atob.

Answer (score 0):

atob does not work in my case, I used this to convert base64 to binary array
[Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file using a base64 file source instead of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url/12094943#12094943)