# jQuery ajax, open PDF in browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use ajax to call function from server, it returns `byte[]` of the *pdf*. How can I display it in browser in readable form in new window?
I can print out the `bytecode` in the `console`, but how can I visualize it in browser? I don't want to download the pdf.

I'm not using **PDF.js**. I only have `JS` and `JQuery`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file using a base64 file source instead of url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url)

Comment: Is there a reason for not using PDF.js? Otherwise you need to convert your byte[] to "data:application/pdf;base64," (does not work on IE for large pdfs) or `URL.createObectURL(new Blob(` which is not supported on older browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You should set  `Content-Type: application/pdf` for return page.
Browsers that has PDF Reader plugin it will open it, browsers that didn't have plugin will propose to download as PDF file

Comment: Ok.... im using grails. ajax sends request to controller. controller constructs the byte[] of the pdf. Then sends it back to the JS. what next, how do i put it on the page. where do i put it ?

Comment: I hope, that link will be useful for you: